# How to generate the set of lines orthogonal to the mid points of a non-intersectional polygon

Tags: polygons

Given a set of N = 10 points that in a known order form a non-intersecting polygon take the line orthogonal to a mid point of a line segment, using the first segment for example, and extract the section of that line from the mid point up to the point where it intersects the polygon as two points $\{p_1, p_2\}$

```
pl = RandomPolygon[10];

pv = PerpendicularBisector[p[[1 ;; 2]]];

Graphics[{pl, pv}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I need the line segment along that line from the mid point to the point at which it intersect an edge of the polygon.So take the region of the intersection between the two, which yields a region formed of two line segments

```
r = RegionIntersection[pl, pv];
Region[r]
```

[image]

The segment I need, and which I cannot find how to extract from the region, is that segment $\{p_1, p_2\}$ in the region where either $p_1$ or $p_2$ is the mid point of

```
p[[1 ;; 2]]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: The obvious rotate the line segment 90 degrees, form the ax + b equation, and look for intersection with the remaining segments each modelled similarly. But that's only part of it. I need it done efficiently and I need to do it when I do not know  which way to rotate so I am inside the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

**modified**

Here as a startup my solution using MeshRegion:

```
poly = RandomPolygon[  10 ]
mreg = MeshRegion[poly]; 
punkte = MeshCoordinates[mreg ];
linien = MeshPrimitives[mreg, 1];

\[Psi] = .35;
\[Chi] = Map[(1 - \[Psi]) #[[1, 1]] + \[Psi] #[[1, 2]] &, linien ]

np = Map[Cross[#[[1, 2]] - #[[1, 1]]] & , linien]
rand = Line[Join[punkte, {punkte[[1]]}]];

sp = MapThread[RegionIntersection[rand, HalfLine[#1, #2 ]] &, {\[Chi], np} ] 
Show[mreg, 
Graphics[{PointSize[.01], Darker[Green], sp, Blue,Point[punkte],Red, Point[\[Chi]], MapThread[Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}] &, {\[Chi], np}] }],AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]